# Truncate not matching part of the string

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I need to truncate part of the string which doesn't match a given pattern. Let's say the string is:

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
```

My matching pattern would be `ipsum dolor` and I would like to truncate all the rest, so that:

```
s.gsub(/_the_pattern_/, '') # => "ipsum dolor"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your word with `_the_pattern_`. Here `.*` means any character.

```
s.gsub(/.*(_the_pattern_).*/, '\1')
```

Make sure the word doesn't contain any special regex characters like `( [ + *` etc.

```
s.gsub(/.*(ipsum dolor).*/, '\1')
```

`\1` is the captured group in `()` from regex matching.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to work for me. Please provde an example of usage with the `ipsum dolor` example I've given.

Comment: Why can't the pattern contain regex characters?  For example, `"My cat".gsub(/.*([ch]at).*/, '\1') => "cat"`, `"My hat".gsub(/.*([ch]at).*/, '\1') => "hat"`.  I don't see the point if the pattern cannot contain such characters.  Won't it always just return the (string representation of the) pattern?  Also, `"my oh my".gsub(/.*(my).*/, '\1') => "my"`.  Shouldn't that be `=> "mymy"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's ok if you know what regex are meaning. I was expecting at best using `\w+` from OP. That's why suggested to take care about it. And the last one, it will be only `my`. The `.*` will eat the first `my`.

Comment: Sabul, I would have thought the asker would have used `sub` if he or she wanted the second `my` to be eaten.  Maybe not, only the asker knows.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"[/_the_pattern_/]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan) followed by [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join) rather than [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), because it is awkward to use the latter for your purpose when the pattern matches more than once. (Since you used `gsub` rather than `sub`, I assume multiple occurrences of the pattern is a possibility.)

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"          #=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" 
pattern = %r[ipsum dolor]                 #=> /ipsum dolor/ 
s.scan(pattern).join                      #=> "ipsum dolor" 

s = "A rose by any other name is a rose." #=> "A rose by any other name is a rose." 
pattern = %r[[Aa]\srose]                  #=> /[Aa]\srose/ 
s.scan(pattern).join                      #=> => "A rosea rose"
```